# Use equivalent of InterWiki links in doxygen documentation markup

Tags: doxygen

Some of my doxygen documentation need to refer to pages in the
company's wiki. I would prefer if these references resulted in working
hypertext links in the generated documentation. I could of course
achieve this by writing:

```
/// <a href="http:://long-URL.com/wiki/index.php?Name-of-page">Name of page</a>
```

or alternatively using Markdown syntax:

```
/// [Name of wiki page](http://long-URL.com/wiki/index.php?Name-of-page)
```

Unfortunately I have to give the full URL at every link in both cases,
and when (as has already happened) the base URL of our company/wiki
changes, all the URLs needs updating.

I therefore wonder if Doxygen has some support to avoid having to
hardcode the entire URL at every link?

For comparison, wikis use "InterMap" or "InterWiki", to define
prefixes that allow a shorthand notation for quickly referring to pages
on another web site. Example:

```
See WikiPedia:InterWiki_Links for more details.
```

So if possible I would like to let the Doxygen documentation contain
something like:

```
// See CompanyWiki:Name_of_wiki_page for bla bla
```

Some references:

- Automatic link generation - http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html
- InterWiki - https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interwiki
- PmWiki/InterMap - http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/InterMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an alias in the config file:

```
ALIASES += WikiPedia{2}="<a href=\"http://long-URL.com/wiki/index.php?\1\">\2</a>"
```

and then use it in your comments like so

```
See \WikiPedia{InterWiki_Links,Interwiki Links} for more details.
```

See also http://www.doxygen.org/manual/custcmd.html for more info.